# Can we call html ids from Wicket Java class

Tags: java, wicket

Is there a way to call ids that are created in html page without specifically giving wicket:id in the component. If so, how can I do that?

What I am trying to accomplish is to get access of the component to assign a default value from CMS. I could assign the default value using JS, however I need that value to be populated to Java so that I could use that in my class to update my business logic depending on the defaulted value.

Comment: I think there is no way to avoid wicket:id from your markup. However, you may remove it from your rendered HTML, but not a good practice in Wicket. If you want you can setOutputId to your desired value. But it's not recommended either.

Comment: @Nishant Yes I agree. Its not that I don't want to see wicket:id in my source as well as setMarkupId gives me the option of giving static wicket:id. But that's not what I want either. For clarification on what I am trying to address I have edited my question. But thanks for your reply

Comment: I still can't understand what are you talking about. Are you trying to add components to a page dynamically, without fixing their `wicket:id`s in the HTML templates?

Comment: Isn't what you're looking for some sort of updating Ajax behavior that you can attach to your component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, Wicket is component oriented which means that single component (piece of HTML code) can't see all the HTML. And my guess is that at some late stage, you want to look at the whole page HTML and do something with a DOM node with a specific ID.

I'm not sure what the correct solution should be. One way is to put the value into the user's session, so it's available for each component and your business logic.

Comment: That's not the point. The OP is not talking about the DOM id, but the wicket:id attribute, which is necessary to map Java Components to HTML code.

Comment: @Sean I am trying to do what actually Aaron is saying but not the full extent of accessing the whole DOM tree, I just need one HTML id's value which can be accessed in Java

Comment: @Amar: What prevents you from using a constant? Does the ID change? If so, can you "fix" that? ID's should be constants.

Comment: Well, the ID doesn't change with setMarkupId("htmlId") through wicket, however accessing the whole DOM tree, I see, needs to be accessed using an XML parser. I am not so keen on using the XML parser to access the whole DOM tree when I need just one HTML id. However, I am not sure if there is a different way to access this id from Java.

Comment: @Aaron Thanks to you. My colleague and I have figured out a way to call the Ajax function in JS to write to Java class and storing the value in session. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Makes me wonder why you can't do this at the place where the HTML code (which contains the ID) is generated. If that happens in Java, it should be simple to put it into the request or the session.